# Choosing strategic spatial data model for Electrical Utility sector?

Tags: data-model

Is there an ideal industry standard spatial data model for an electrical utility company (and which utilities use it) that has a mix of linear & point assets or is it better to develop a custom model?

What are the pros and cons for adopting an industry standard model in this area?

Comment: What type of utilities are we talking about here.  Water, WW, Storm Water, Electrical, etc.. each has a different standard.

Comment: If using ESRI software, and want a good place to start, whether you want to develop your own or use an existing model, ESRI provides data models for [utility and pipeline](http://solutions.arcgis.com/utilities/gas/help/utility-pipeline-data-model/), [water](http://solutions.arcgis.com/utilities/water/help/network-editing/), [stormwater](http://solutions.arcgis.com/utilities/water/help/stormwater-network/), and [electric](http://downloads2.esri.com/support/TechArticles/Energy_Utilities.pdf).

Comment: Electrical utilities.

Answer (score 0):

Esri have several pages specific to electricity industry:

[Esri - Electric](http://www.esri.com/industries/electric)
[Energy Utilities (includes ArcGIS MultiSpeak) Data Model](http://downloads2.esri.com/support/TechArticles/Energy_Utilities.pdf) (PDF)
[ArcGIS for Electric and Gas](http://www.arcgis.com/home/group.html?owner=TeamElectricGas&title=ArcGIS%20for%20Electric%20and%20Gas)

Some of the downloads on those pages may also include a pre-built geodatabase using an electric data-model that can be used to create your own.  We used their water-network model to create ours and it has worked out well, plus there are many tools and apps (also mentioned in those links) that can connect into that model.